# Hide the submit button if there's no generated input fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, hide

I would like to hide my submit button if there's not input fields in a div (maybe with a specific id for the inputs and check if there are present or not?)

Because I generate some inputs fields by pressing some buttons I have a "Save fields" button which need to appear only if you generated some fields.

I would like to trick this with jQuery, any idea?

Comment: Seems like an easier method would be to just hide the submit by default and make it visible in the function that generates fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$("#form input").length > 0) $("#sumbit").hide();
```

Quite simple!

Comment: Yes this may work great but my input fields are generated by pressing some buttons so they are dynamic so you can have 2,3,4 but you can delete them and don't have any so I need to "refresh" the state to tell the "submit" button to hide

Comment: Ok I've fix by add this piece of code on each function which is dependant of the generated fields, not the best way imho but works fine. Maybe there's something more "global" to count each input field in the DOM

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this. Fosco has a great suggestion of making the submit button hidden by default, and only showing it if the number of `<input>` elements is `> 0`

Furthermore, use the [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) or [length()](http://api.jquery.com/length/) function to get the number of elements of a particular type, or class. If that value is `0`, then use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) on the submit button to hide it, and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) if it's `> 0`.